# Random planes separating points in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability, mg.metric-geometry, probability-distributions, geometric-probability

We are given a unit origin-centered sphere $S$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$, and three points $\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y},\mathbf{z}\in S$. Let $\mathbf{h}$ be a point selected uniformly at random from $S$ and let $H$ be a hyperplane that passes through the center $\mathbf{0}$ of $S$ and has $\mathbf{h}$ as normal vector. Let $E_x$ be the event that $H$ separates $\mathbf{x}$ from the other two points $\mathbf{y}$ and $\mathbf{z}$.

**Questions**: What is the probability of $E_x$? How can we extend this result to express the probability of separating $\mathbf{x}$ from other $n-1$ points when there are $n$ points instead of only three?

---

***Note:*** *I conjecture that the answer to the first question is $\frac12\left(\arccos\left(\mathbf{x}^{\top}\mathbf{y}\right)+\arccos\left(\mathbf{x}^{\top}\mathbf{z}\right)-\arccos\left(\mathbf{y}^{\top}\mathbf{z}\right)\right)$.*

Comment: Note that $H$ separates $x$ from $y$ and $z$ if and only if $h^\perp x \cdot h^\perp y<0$ and $h^\perp x\cdot h^\perp z<0$. You didn't say what is the law of $h$, but if you know the marginal probability distributions, then you can compute everything.

Comment: Might as well assume that $x$ is the point $(1,0,0)$.  There is a half-circle of planes through  $0$ and $x$. Denote by $\alpha$ the angle between the planes $oxy$ and $oxz$. The probability is $\alpha/\pi$.

Comment: You probably mean $\frac12\left(\arccos\left(\mathbf{x}^{\top}\mathbf{y}\right)+\arccos\left(\mathbf{x}^{\top}\mathbf{z}\right)-\arccos\left(\mathbf{y}^{\top}\mathbf{z}\right)\right)$

Comment: Thank you @YaakovBaruch, there was a typo.

Comment: @LiviuNicolaescu, thank you for your answer! How can we generalize it for the case in which we have $\mathbf{x}$ and $n-1$ other points when $n>3$?

Comment: @M.Dus sorry, I did not understand why you wrote that I "didn't say wha is the law of $\mathbf{h}$", while I wrote "[...] Let $\mathbf{h}$ be a point *selected uniformly at random* from $S$ ".

Comment: @PenelopeBenenati  The problem is equivalent to the following. Suppose that you have $n-1$ points on a circle. What is  the probability  that a uniformly chosen  random diameter leaves $k$ of them on one side and $n-1-k$ on the other side.   The special case $n-1=4$ and the points are the vertices of a square shows  that for $k=2$ the probability is $1$ while for other $k$țs the answer is zero. The answer is dependent on the configuration of those $(n-1)$ points. At one extreme they can be clustered and at the other extrem uniformly distributed.

Comment: Thank you @LiviuNicolaescu !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that the random vector $G/\|G\|$ is uniformly distributed on the unit sphere in $\mathbb R^n$, where $G$ is a standard Gaussian random vector in $\mathbb R^n$.

So, given an $n$-tuple $(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ of unit vectors in $\mathbb R^n$, the probability that the random hyperplane separates $x_1$ from $x_2,\dots,x_n$
is
$$p_n:=2P(X_1>0,X_2<0,\dots,X_n<0),$$
where $X_j:=x_j\cdot G$ for $j=1,\dots,n$, so that the covariance matrix of $(X_1,\dots,X_n)$ is the Gram matrix of $(x_1,\dots,x_n)$.

Schläfli (1858) obtained a differential recurrence relation for probabilities of the form $p_n/2$; see e.g. [Plackett](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2332716?seq=1) and references there. Using this recurrence for $n\le4$, $p_n$ can be expressed as an integral of elementary functions.
As pointed out by [Ruben. p. 213](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2333017?seq=1),
"For dimensionality greater than three (spherical tetrahedra, spherical pentahedra, etc.) the areas can no longer be expressed in terms of elementary functions".